# Определить, сколько элементов списка содержат по 3 слова, по 2 и по одному

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
queries = [
'смотреть сериалы онлайн',
'новости спорта',
'афиша кино',
'курс доллара',
'сериалы этим летом',
'курс по питону',
'сериалы про спорт'
]
for i in queries:
  if " " in i:
   print(i)
```

Есть список. Надо определить, сколько элементов с 3 словами, с 2-мя и одним. Моя мысль такова: Если три слова в элементе, то два пробела. Если 2 слова, то пробел один. Но вот, незадача Я пробовал условием искать пробел, но выходит найти только один и в итоге возвращает тот же список, потому что дин пробел имеют все элементы. Как составить проверку, чтобы питон искал 2 пробела или один. Или возможно нужно выбрать другой критерий сортировки? Помогите плиз

Comment: `i.count(" ")`.

Comment: Для подсчёта количества вхождений конкретного символа в строку у строки есть метод [`.count(символ)`](https://docs-python.ru/tutorial/operatsii-tekstovymi-strokami-str-python/metod-str-count/).

Comment: но если может быть несколько пробелов подряд, то такой способ может давать ошибки

Comment: Вариант в одну строчку: `print(*(f"слов: {w} => элементов в списке: {e}" for w, e in __import__("collections").Counter(map(lambda x: len(x.split()), queries)).items()), sep="\n")` :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если нужно считать слова, то и нужно считать слова, а не пробелы. Функцией `split()` разделить строку на список слов и посчитать его длину:

```
queries = [
'смотреть сериалы онлайн',
'новости спорта',
'афиша   кино',
'курс доллара',
'сериалы этим летом',
'курс по  питону для  начинающих',
'сериалы   про  спорт'
] # для наглядности в некоторых местах больше одного пробела, на результат не влияет
two, three = 0, 0
for el in queries:
    words = el.split()
    if len(words) == 2:
        print("2 слова")
        two += 1
    elif len(words) == 3:
        print("3 слова")
        three += 1
    else:
        print("другое количество слов")
```

Comment: спасибо, ответ супер. Но ещё не могли бы помочь определить количество элементов с 2 мя. 3мя. Я хочу вести то сколько % запросов соответствует 2ум словам 3м словам

Comment: создайте две переменных и увеличивайте их в нужной if-ветке

Answer (score 2):

```
res = [(x,len(x.split())) for x in queries]
```

res:

```
[('смотреть сериалы онлайн', 3),
 ('новости спорта', 2),
 ('афиша кино', 2),
 ('курс доллара', 2),
 ('сериалы этим летом', 3),
 ('курс по питону', 3),
 ('сериалы про спорт', 3)]
```